# Photoshop script to get image layer transform infomation

Tags: photoshop, extendscript

As show in the image below,

How to get the width, height and rotation angle in Photoshop scripts.

[Get Layer width, height and rotation angle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1syN.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need two things. First a function to grab the layer as a selection. Secondly, you need to get the layer bounds - from which you can work out the height and width.

```
var currentLayer = app.activeDocument.activeLayer.name;
var currentLayerSelection = layer_selection();
var lb = get_selection_bounds();

alert(currentLayer + " layer bounds:\n" + lb[0] + ", " + lb[1] + ", " + lb[2] + ", " + lb[3]);




// function GET SELECTION BOUNDS ()
// ----------------------------------------------------------------
function get_selection_bounds()
{
  try
  {
    var x = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[0]);
    var y = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[1]);
    var x1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[2]);
    var y1 = parseFloat(app.activeDocument.selection.bounds[3]);

    var selW = parseFloat(x1-x);
    var selH = parseFloat(y1-y);

    // return the results as an array
    return [x, y, x1, y1];
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    alert("Oops " + e)
  }
}

function layer_selection()
{
  var id1268 = charIDToTypeID( "setd" );
  var desc307 = new ActionDescriptor();
  var id1269 = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
  var ref257 = new ActionReference();
  var id1270 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id1271 = charIDToTypeID( "fsel" );
  ref257.putProperty( id1270, id1271 );
  desc307.putReference( id1269, ref257 );
  var id1272 = charIDToTypeID( "T   " );
  var ref258 = new ActionReference();
  var id1273 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id1274 = charIDToTypeID( "Chnl" );
  var id1275 = charIDToTypeID( "Trsp" );
  ref258.putEnumerated( id1273, id1274, id1275 );
  desc307.putReference( id1272, ref258 );
  executeAction( id1268, desc307, DialogModes.NO )

}
```

You can work out the height and width:

```
var layerWidth  = lb[2] - lb[0]; 
var layerHeight = lb[3] - lb[1]; 
alert("Width, height: " + layerWidth + ", " + layerHeight);
```

As for the angle.. Let's just say it's much easier to do that yourself.

Use the ruler tool - then Photoshop will work out the angle. Look in Image > Image Rotation > Arbitrary and it'll show you the angle to rotate the canvas to get it back to horizontal.

Comment: Hi, @Ghoul Fool, Thanks for your answer, again.
Just test your script, it runs fine, but seems the Width and Height it output is the size of the bounding box of the image layer.
I known how to use the ruler to measure the angle, and rotate the image layer back to horizontal. I need some script way to get those info for some Photoshop script.